# How to get the Woocommerce API to not upload images when creating product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm using the Woocommerce API to create products, and passing in an array of image urls. The images are on S3, and I just want Wordpress to reference those, but by default the Woocommerce API uploads the images to Wordpress and references those.

Any ideas how I can change this behavior so that the just takes the remote image URL's and uses those?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not possible WooCommerce uses the Post ID of photo uploaded to WordPress as it's primary identifier (key) to reference those images...

If you DO find out how to do that, that would be huge!!

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can pass the image as a parameter of products from the third party URL. still, it is not accessing from the phone.

try like this

```
"images": [
{
  "src": "http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg",
  "position": 0
},
{
  "src": "http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_back.jpg",
  "position": 1
}
```

]

You can find the more information from the docs of woocommerce REST API.

Visit https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product

Comment: this uploads the images to the server. What he wants to avoid. I tested it. Your answer is wrong.